# How can I host Google Image Charts on my own servers?

Tags: math, charts

https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/formulas

Image Charts are deprecated. I can't find the source. The replacement, using JS, doesn't appear to handle mathematics, which is what I was interested in. Is there source available to host it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, found a better way: http://www.mathjax.org/

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of Image-Charts.

I built a drop-in-replacement for Google Image Charts called [**Image-Charts**](http://image-charts.com) exactly for that. You can host it on our own server or use the forever-free SaaS version.